# Find a graph where $|E| = 2|V|-3$ and $\deg (v) = 3$ for every $v$

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone help me find a graph where $|E| = 2|V|-3$ and $\deg(v) = 3$ for every $v$?

Comment: you certainly didn't try very hard.

Comment: Well I'm out of focus that's for sure, but I still can't find it :O

Comment: It did not occur to you to start with the graph with just 2 vertices and 1 edge? I fail to comprehend how you could have spent hours. What did you try?

Comment: Oh I didn't mention that deg(v) = 3 for every v!

Comment: That drastically changes the triviality of the problem...

Comment: Out of focus indeed

Comment: Hint: $\text{deg}(v) = 3$ gives you a second equation relating $|E|$ and $|V|$.  Solve this and you'll know exactly how large the graph has to be instead of randomly guessing for hours.

Comment: I thought it'll get there, I tried to find the formula but couldn't do it :\

Comment: Thanks! your answer helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-regular graph has number of edges

$e = \frac{K.v}{2}=\frac{3.v}{2}$

Your equation is,

$e = 2.v-3$

From both ,

$2.v-3 = \frac{3.v}{2}$

$4.v-6 = 3.v$

$v = 6$

Therefore, number of edges $e=9$.

So, it's a complete bipartite of three nodes graph. i.e., $k_{3,3}$.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Take $V=\{ x_1, x_2 \}$  and $E=\{\overline{x_1 x_2 }\}.$